# JavaFX - Combine two CellFactory - TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn() and custom one

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableColumn:

```
TableColumn<Foo, String> colStatus = new TableColumn("Status");
colStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("statusElement"));
```

On this table I want to apply this cellFactory `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` which will make cell editable.

But I also want to combine this one with a custom cellFactory:

```
colStatus.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {

    public TableCell<Foo, String> call(TableColumn param) {

        return new TableCell<>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (!isEmpty()){

                    if(item.equals("error")){

                        this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                        setText(item);

                    }else{

                        this.setTextFill(Color.Black);
                        setText(item);

                    }

                }

            }
        };
    }

});
```

This cell factory sets text color of cell, based by cell value.

But I don't know how to make the cell editable but also to customize his color, based on value.

Here is MCVE:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("done(green)");
    test.add("done(green)");
    test.add("fail(red)");
    test.add("done(green)");

    TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column");
    col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
    col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    //I want to apply a color based by value from cell

    tableView.getColumns().add(col);

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(test));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));

    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://o7planning.org/en/11079/javafx-tableview-tutorial

Comment: you can subclass TextFieldTableCell just the same as any other cell

Comment: @Sedrick How I can give a `Minimal, Reproducible Example` when I don't have code for what I want. My problem is not an error. Also your link don't help me. I know how to make cell editable, but I don't know how to make text of cell colorful, when it is editable.

Comment: @kleopatra I call `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` which is a static method which return a `CallBack` which make my cell editable. I want to edit that `CallBack` to apply, besides editable cell, a color to text, based on value.

Comment: No one wants to recreate a whole project to fix your code. At the very least you can post code of a running program up to the point where you are. That way we can copy that code and edit it instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @Sedrick I'm sorry for my misunderstood. I added a sample code.

Comment: Note that your `TableCell` implementation is incomplete: `updateItem` needs to be able to deal with the case when the cell becomes empty. Otherwise you'll get unexpected results, if you remove items from the table or grow the size of the table in a way that results in empty rows being shown...

Answer (score 1):

The key is to `extend` `TableCell` as @fabian suggested.

> Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("done(green)");
        test.add("done(green)");
        test.add("fail(red)");
        test.add("done(green)");

        TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column");
        col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory((param) -> new CustomCellFactory());
        //I want to apply a color based by value from cell

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);

        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(test));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> CustomCellFactory

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CustomCellFactory<T> extends TableCell<T, String>
{

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Text text = new Text();

    public CustomCellFactory()
    {
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String newValue)
    {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        super.startEdit();
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            textField.setText(text.getText());
            Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
        }
        else {
            if (item.equals("error")) {
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
            else {
                text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            }

            text.setText(item);
            setGraphic(text);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

> Update: I found [This](https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357#file-editcell-java-L109) while failing to live up to @kleopatra suggestion.

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("done(green)");
        test.add("done(green)");
        test.add("fail(red)");
        test.add("done(green)");

        TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column");
        col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());
        //I want to apply a color based by value from cell

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);

        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(test));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**EditCell**

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class EditCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T>
{

    // Text field for editing
    // TODO: allow this to be a plugable control.
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    // Converter for converting the text in the text field to the user type, and vice-versa:
    private final StringConverter<T> converter;

    public EditCell(StringConverter<T> converter)
    {
        this.converter = converter;

        itemProperty().addListener((obx, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (newItem == null) {
                setText(null);
            }
            else {
                setText(converter.toString(newItem));
            }
        });
        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
            commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
        });
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (!isNowFocused) {
                commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
            }
        });
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (null != event.getCode()) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case ESCAPE:
                        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
                        cancelEdit();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectRightCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectLeftCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case UP:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Convenience converter that does nothing (converts Strings to themselves
     * and vice-versa...).
     */
    public static final StringConverter<String> IDENTITY_CONVERTER = new StringConverter<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public String toString(String object)
        {
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String fromString(String string)
        {
            return string;
        }

    };

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating an EditCell for a String value.
     *
     * @param <S>
     * @return
     */
    public static <S> EditCell<S, String> createStringEditCell()
    {
        return new EditCell<>(IDENTITY_CONVERTER);
    }

    // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }

    // revert to text display
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    // commits the edit. Update property if possible and revert to text display
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T item)
    {

        // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
        // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
        // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
        if (!isEditing() && !item.equals(getItem())) {
            TableView<S> table = getTableView();
            if (table != null) {
                TableColumn<S, T> column = getTableColumn();
                CellEditEvent<S, T> event = new CellEditEvent<>(table,
                        new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                Event.fireEvent(column, event);
            }
        }

        if (item.equals("error")) {
            setTextFill(Color.RED);
        }
        else {
            setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        super.commitEdit(item);

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}
```

Comment: actually .. no. don't re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: the wheel here would be TextFieldTableCell :) Why don't you go from there?

Comment: Thank you Sedrick! `startEdit()` was the implementation I was needed. Also, I'm curious how I can use `TextFieldTableCell`, as @kleopatra said.

Comment: I have a problem. After cancel edit, cell appear empty.

Comment: KunLun, I was waiting on @kleopatra to respond. There may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Initially I was thinking, somehow, to use `TextFieldTableCell`, but I don't know how. That's why I want to see kleopatra's answer.

Comment: @Sedrick I found the way. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

I finally found I can use `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` with customization.

Just need to override `TextFieldTableCell`.

```
private static class CustomCell extends TextFieldTableCell<String, String>{

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            return;
        }

        if(!isEmpty()){

            if(item.equals("error")){

                this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                setText(item);

            }else{

                this.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                setText(item);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I was fixed on idea that `setCellFactory` get as parameter a `CallBack`.

So I was tried a lot of ways to get a `CallBack` which returns a `TableCell`

After I saw the answer of @Sedrick.

I found I can send an lambda implementation like: `setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCell())`.

Thanks to @Sedrick and @kleopatra.

Comment: That's what I was looking into when I found the update I posted. The update is by James_D. A highly decorated StackOverflow guy but it's still recreating the whell.

Comment: Good job at figuring it out!

Comment: @Sedrick That `EditCell` is an complex implementation. Somehow a wheel with updates :P. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

class className {
    private void initColumnTableValue() {
        TableColumn<User, Number> columnId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        columnId.setCellFactory(getTextFieldCellFactoryId());
    }


    /*
     * Returns the factory to a cell with a text field for editing
     * but with the ability to customize cells
     */
    private Callback<TableColumn<User, Number>, TableCell<User, Number>> getTextFieldCellFactoryId() {
        return CustomTextFieldTableCell.<User, Number>forTableColumn(
                new StringConverter<Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString(Number number) {
                        return number == null ? "" : number.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Number fromString(String s) {
                        try {
                            return Integer.valueOf(s);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a changed factory for the production of editable cells, 
 * but with the ability to customize cells
 */
public class CustomTextFieldTableCell extends TextFieldTableCell<User, Number> {
    public CustomTextFieldTableCell(StringConverter<Number> var0) {super(var0);}
    { setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER); }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Number value, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(value, empty);
        if (value == null || empty)
            setText("");
        else {
            if ((int)value % 2 == 0)
                setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLUE, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED,
                        new CornerRadii(4), new BorderWidths(1))));
            setText(value.toString());
        }
    }

    public static <User, Number> Callback<TableColumn<User, Number>, TableCell<User, Number>> forTableColumn(StringConverter<Number> var0) {
        return new Callback<TableColumn<User, Number>, TableCell<User, Number>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<User, Number> call(TableColumn<User, Number> var1) {
                return (TableCell<User, Number>) new CustomTextFieldTableCell((StringConverter<java.lang.Number>) var0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```